# Parsing JSON within JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitch

I am using the Twitch API and am attempting to pull follower images. To do this, I have to parse my most recent followers, take the name of these followers and make a request for each to obtain their user image.

```
$.getJSON(streamFollowers, function(json) {

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var followerDisplayName = json.follows[i].user.display_name;
  var followerName = json.follows[i].user.name;
  var followerJSON = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + followerName + '';

$.getJSON(followerJSON, function(json) {
  var followerImage = json.logo;
  if (followerImage === "null") {
    followerImage = "null.jpg";
  };
});
```

What I am having difficulty with is attempting to pull the "followerImage" result from the "followerJSON" parse.

Heres the code in action. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxEPXQ

Edit: A second parse isn't required. You can pull user images from the initial parse for usernames etc. I just didn't see see it at the time. My bad.

Comment: The issue seems to be that the requests are unauthenticated, the logo field is the correct one, but it is `null` when no API key/oauth token is used

Comment: @RobM. I'm not sure if the requests need to use an API key. You should be able to pull any users account information.

Ex: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_dyrus

I'm new to this so I'm unsure if theres a difference in accessing the information by viewing it in a browser versus parsing it with jQuery.

Comment: A users logo is null if a user doesn't have a profile picture set.

Comment: `"null.jpg"` isn't a valid path to a real image. Examine the data returned will see all the `json.logo` have no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A users logo is null if a user doesn't have a profile picture set.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPBMox?editors=1011

here it is with all your followers, you can see ones with it set work properly.

```
var streamFollowers = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/tsm_dyrus/follows";
$.getJSON(streamFollowers, function(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.follows.length; i++) {
    var followerDisplayName = json.follows[i].user.display_name;
    var followerName = json.follows[i].user.name;
    var followerImage = json.follows[i].user.logo;
    $('#followers').append('<li><img src="' + followerImage + '"></img><br />' + followerDisplayName + '</li>');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is working for the images, however the usernames loop the last name parsed.

Comment: Holy cow I completely missed that the original parse returned the "logo". I didn't see it so I thought I'd have to run a second parse for logos on each individual user. Wow. I'm ashamed of myself.

Thank you so much for your help.